# C# Read text from right side

Tags: c#, regex, replace, substring, right-to-left

I using actually this scripts:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader_org = select_org.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader_org.Read())
    {
        if (reader_org.IsDBNull(1) | reader_org.IsDBNull(0))
        continue;

        int cislo = reader_org.GetInt32(0);
        string s = reader_org.GetString(1);
        string ulice;
        Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d+)");
        string cp = m.Groups[0].Value;
        if (cp.Length > 0)
        {
            s = s.Replace(cp, "").Trim();
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(cp);
        }
        if (s.Contains('/'))
        {
            Match l = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d+)");
            string co = l.Groups[0].Value;
            if (co.Length > 0)
            {
                s = s.Replace(co, "").Trim();
                int number = Convert.ToInt32(co);
            }
            s = s.Replace('/', ' ').Trim();
            Definitions.co.Add(co);
            MessageBox.Show("CO: " + co);
        }
        ulice = s;
        Definitions.Subjekt.Add(cislo);
        Definitions.Ulice.Add(ulice);
        Definitions.cp.Add(cp);
        MessageBox.Show("Adresa " + ulice + " " + cp);
    }
}
```

my string s get this data in while: (Complete address)

```
                                                  // I need every value separately
Complete address - >                              Streets        House number       OC
5 renvan 5 /13                                   5 renvan             5              13
5 renwan 13                                      5 renwan             13             0
Terak 516                                        Terak                516            0
Terak 516/87                                     Terak                516            87
Timbron 5 87 /69                                 Timbron 5             87            69
```

But now i get first number int text but if i will read from right site so my problem will be fixed, can you help me please how can i fix this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you want accomplish. I'm not sure that reading from right to left solve issue, you just need create correct regular expression and take everything you want immediately. But again, I merely don't understand question.

Comment: So ok.

Complete adress is values what i earn in my string "s" in scripts.

But my script now catch first number from texts and if text contaions  this char (/) so i repeat function for select number.

But i need earn only house number and oc but streetName contaions too number but it is not house number but my script now select too but i dont need it. Do you understand me now? But if i will read from right side so my script will be work because first number from right side is correct for house number or contaions (/) so i earn two number values what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some code and if I understood correctly it can solve your problem. If not, then adjust it for your needs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var input = new List<string>() { 
            @"5 renvan 5 /13",
@"5 renwan 13",
@"Terak 516  ",
@"Terak 516/87",
"Timbron 5 87 /69"};

            foreach (var item in input)
            {
                var workItem = item.Trim().Replace("/", " ").Split(' ').Where(i => "" != i.Trim()).ToList();


                if (workItem.Count() > 1)
                {
                    string firstRightDigit = workItem[workItem.Count() - 1];
                    string secondRightDigit = workItem[workItem.Count() - 2];

                    int CO = 0;
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(secondRightDigit, out CO))
                    {
                        secondRightDigit = firstRightDigit;
                        firstRightDigit = "0";
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("House number: {0} \t\t CO:{1}", secondRightDigit, firstRightDigit));
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

** ADDED **

I arrived to my workplace and create another solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = new List<string>() { 
            @"5 renvan 5 /13",
            @"5 renwan 13",
            @"Terak 516  ",
            @"Terak 516/87 ",
            @"Timbron 5 827 /619",
            @"Timbron 5 980 / 69   ",
            @"Timbron 5 187 / 121"};

            input.ForEach(item => {
                Match match = Regex.Match(item, @"(\d+)(\s*)?/?(\s*\d+\s*)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Input string: {0,20}\tResult House #: {1,5}\tCO:{2,5}",
                    item,
                    match.Groups[1].Value.Trim(),
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups[3].Value.Trim()) ? "0" : match.Groups[3].Value.Trim()));
            });

        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you added to writeline adress without house number, CO and "/" if contains?